# No GUI or login shell on boot

Tags: bash, debian, tty, gnome3, display-manager

When I boot my pc (Debian 12 with Gnome3) I get directly taken to a blinking line instead of a login promt or a GUI. From there I can switch tty (Alt + F2) and then get a login promt and after login I'm able to start Gnome using `startx`.

(Sorry for extremely bad image)

[image]

So I guess this is a double question...

1. How to fix so that I get a login promt on tty1 so I do not need to switch everytime I start my pc?
2. How to automatically start Gnome desktop environment before login?

---

Update #1

I looked in `/etc/gdm3/deamon.conf` (only conf file in the directory) and the line said `#WaylandEnable=false` so I changed it to `WaylandEnable=false`.

I also checked and both gdm3.service and gdm.service and both was enabled (`systemctl status ...`).

I then rebooted my pc and there was no difference.

After I logged in (after switching tty) I checked the conf file and my change was still there.

I also did `systemctl status gdm3.service` and `systemctl status gdm3.service` both were enabled and green.

---

Update #2

So I tried a `systemctl status` after I logged in via terminal in a new tty and it displayed no faults unfortunately.
[image]

I also tried:
[image]

And also:
[image]
to no avail.

Comment: Probably `systemctl enable getty@tty1` / `systemctl enable gdm`

Comment: It was already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If `startx` works, then you apparently have working X.org X11 graphics drivers. However, they might be generic unaccelerated VESA SVGA or EFI GOP drivers instead of accelerated drivers specific to your GPU type. But an unaccelerated GUI might be better than no GUI at all.

---

Perhaps your system is currently configured to attempt to use Wayland instead of X11, and it is failing?

Read the configuration file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. If there is a commented-out line:

```
#WaylandEnabled=false
```

then the system is configured for Wayland. To force X11 instead of Wayland,
change the line to:

```
WaylandEnabled=false
```

Then run `systemctl restart gdm` or reboot.

If that does not help, undo your change.

---

Maybe your system has been set to boot to text-mode only?

Run `systemctl get-default`. If it does **not** respond `graphical.target`, then your system is not set to boot to GUI mode. Before changing the default boot target, test it first so you don't end up in a more difficult situation:

```
systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

This should switch the system to GUI mode in a non-persistent way: if something goes wrong, just reboot and you'll be back where you started. If you get a working GUI login prompt, make the GUI mode persistent with:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

---

Maybe something is failing in the boot process?

Run `systemctl status` to see the overall system status. On the second line, there should be either `State: running` (in green if your terminal supports colours) if `systemd` thinks it has successfully started everything it needs to start, or `State: degraded` (in red if colours supported) if something has failed, or `State: starting` if `systemd` has not quite finished the boot process yet (i.e. some service might be hanging or stuck in an infinite loop, or something).

To find out which service(s) have failed, run

```
systemctl --failed
```

If the boot process does not seem to reach completion, run

```
systemctl --state=start
```

to find any services (or other units) that `systemd` might be stuck trying to start or restart.

Then check `systemctl status <name of failed/stuck unit>` and/or `journalctl -b0 -u <name of failed/stuck unit>` to get more information about the failure.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunatly it did not work.

Comment: I added some more things to check.

Comment: Still not working! 